What is the identity of this zeta function?
There are a Riemann zeta function, a Hurwitz zeta function, and many different types of zeta functions. However, I saw the zeta function below in a Japanese blog.
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{-(m+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{m}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{m}{j}j^{-s}$$
So, I want to know about this zeta function's name and what mathematically meaningful information there is that can be found when a function is written in this format(In other words, the motivation for writing it in this format).

Are you sure you didn't miscopy the first sum? It seems that it should be $\sum_{m=0}^\infty$ instead of $\sum_{m=1}^n$; in that case, this would be the actual Riemann zeta function, as the blog seems to be indicating and as Mathematica can verify.

@GregMartin Hello, Thank you for your comment! I edited my question

The identity of the Riemann zeta function is known as Hasse's representations for zeta function. That can be shown easily. First, we defined the forward difference operator as follows.
$$
\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)
$$
where f is a formal power series of $x$. Now, let’s consider the following transformation, assuming $f=\sum_{0\le n}a_nx^n$
\begin{align}
e^Df(x)
&=\sum_{0\le n}\frac1{n!}D^nf(x)\\
&=\sum_{0\le n}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{0\le n}\frac1{n!}\sum_{0\le r}r(r-1)\dots(r-n+1)a_r\\
&=\sum_{0\le r}a_r\sum_{n=0}^r\binom rnx^{r-n}\\
&=f(x+1)
\end{align}
So we get the identity $e^D-1=\Delta$. This implies
\begin{align}
D&=\ln(1+\Delta)\\
\implies \frac D{1-e^D}&=-\frac{\ln(1+\Delta)}\Delta\\
\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty f'(n+x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom {n-1}kf(x+k)
\end{align}
In the above identity, consider the case where $f=(1+t)^{1-s}$(formal series of $t$) then
$$
-(s-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+1+t)^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k+1+t)^{s-1}}\binom{n-1}k
$$
By comparing the constant terms,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}=\frac1{s-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{s-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{1}
$$
This result is what we desired. This representation of the Riemann zeta function seems complicated, but (1) is convergence for all $s\in \mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$. In this sense, (1) is an extension of the original definition.

Hello, Thank you for your answer! Excuse me if not, but did you refer to paper A new proof of H.Hasse's global expression for the Riemann zeta function In this paper, this Riemann zeta function form was derived from Hurwitz zeta function, If then motivation of this Riemann zeta form was Hurwitz zeta function?

For operator identities, I have needed to show the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula for formal power series, therefore I used that method. Hasse's representation of Huerwitz zeta function is the analytic connection for the definition of that originally, so I think the basic motivation is almost the same.

I got it! Thank you for your comment!!

Through this site, which was also linked to a Japanese blog, I learned that the formula below was guessed by Knoop and proven by Hasse in 1930. Also, this formula is created through Euler's transformation.
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{-(m+1)}\sum_{j=1}^{m}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{m}{j}j^{-s}$$
And the origin of this formula seems to be the result of Euler's use of the Abel summation and Euler-Maclaurin sum formula and Euler's transformation to calculate $\zeta(-m)$. It seems that this formula was explained in terms of Bernoulli numbers, which led to such a complex expression.
